# subir archivo a servidor en la nube con Net 6

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-6.0

tengo una api rest con Net 6, me colocaron que debo subir ficheros a un servidor en la nube pero sin usar php, yo con php si lo se hacer, investigando ya se que con jquery no se puede, decidi hacerlo por la parte del Net, ya tengo mi codigo, pero me sube el archivo en el mismo proyecto en el que tengo la API REST mas no al servidor de la nube, he cambiado toda clase de codigo pero todavia no puedo. agradezco su ayuda

este es mi controller que al momento ha llegado mas lejos (pero me guarda las imagenes dentro de una carpeta donde esta almacenada la API REST)

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
namespace API_Mangoo.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class FilesController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _webHostEnvironment;
        public FilesController(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
        {
            _webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        }
        [HttpPost("Upload")]
        public IActionResult Upload(IFormFile file)
        {
            try
            {
                if(file.Length == 0)
                    return BadRequest();

                var path = Path.Combine(_webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath, "Files");
                if (!Directory.Exists(path))
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
                }

                string fullPath = Path.Combine(path, file.FileName);
                using(var stream = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    file.CopyTo(stream);
                }
                return Ok(file);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]